# How to restart Azure App Service instances one by one using Azure Logic App on a schedule?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an App Service which is running on multiple instances and also has a CI/CD set, so WebJobs isn't really an option here. I've found an elegant solution with a Logic App and Azure API but I was only able to schedule a restart of the whole App Service. This works fine, but it will cause some downtime. I would like to restart instances one by one using the same Logic App + API approach to decrease the downtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to set the Logic App to iterate through all App Service instances and reboot workers in the App Service Plan one by one, using a suggestion from @VenkateshDodda

1. Create an App Registration and obtain a Client Secret.
2. Grant permissions for user_impersonation in Azure Service Management -> API permissions inside your App Registration
3. Grant permissions for your App Registration in the App Service Plan and App Service under Access Control.
4. Paste the attached complete code into your Logic App.
5. Modify it with your client_secret, tenant_id, subscription_id, resourceGroup, appServicePlan, appServiceName, etc:

   ```
    {
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each_instance_Reboot_and_Wait": {
                "actions": {
                    "Delay": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "interval": {
                                "count": 1,
                                "unit": "Hour"
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "HTTP": [
                                "Succeeded",
                                "TimedOut",
                                "Skipped"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Wait"
                    },
                    "HTTP": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "authentication": {
                                "type": "Raw",
                                "value": "Bearer @{body('Parse_OAuth_Token')?['access_token']}"
                            },
                            "headers": {
                                "Content-Type": "application/json"
                            },
                            "method": "POST",
                            "uri": "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/{appServicePlan}/workers/@{items('For_each_instance_Reboot_and_Wait')?['properties']?['machineName']}/reboot?api-version=2022-03-01"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Http"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Parse_Instances_Names')?['value']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_Instances_Names": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "concurrency": {
                        "repetitions": 1
                    }
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "HTTP_-_Get_All_Instances": {
                "inputs": {
                    "authentication": {
                        "type": "Raw",
                        "value": "Bearer @{body('Parse_OAuth_Token')?['access_token']}"
                    },
                    "headers": {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    },
                    "method": "GET",
                    "uri": "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{appServiceName}/instances?api-version=2022-03-01"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_OAuth_Token": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Http"
            },
            "HTTP_-_Token": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={client_id}client_secret={client_secret}&resource=https://management.core.windows.net/",
                    "headers": {
                        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                    },
                    "method": "POST",
                    "uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Http"
            },
            "Parse_Instances_Names": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@body('HTTP_-_Get_All_Instances')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "id": {},
                            "nextLink": {},
                            "value": {
                                "items": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "id": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "location": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "name": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "properties": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "consoleUrl": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "containers": {},
                                                "detectorUrl": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "healthCheckUrl": {},
                                                "machineName": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "name": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "siteInstanceName": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "state": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "statusUrl": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "type": "object"
                                        },
                                        "type": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "required": [
                                        "id",
                                        "name",
                                        "type",
                                        "location",
                                        "properties"
                                    ],
                                    "type": "object"
                                },
                                "type": "array"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "HTTP_-_Get_All_Instances": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Parse_OAuth_Token": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@body('HTTP_-_Token')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "access_token": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "expires_in": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "expires_on": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "ext_expires_in": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "not_before": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "resource": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "token_type": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "HTTP_-_Token": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "appServiceName": {
                "defaultValue": "{appServiceName}",
                "type": "String"
            },
            "appServicePlan": {
                "defaultValue": "{appServicePlan}",
                "type": "String"
            },
            "resourceGroup": {
                "defaultValue": "{resourceGroup}",
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Day",
                    "interval": 1,
                    "schedule": {
                        "hours": [
                            "6",
                            "0",
                            "14"
                        ],
                        "minutes": [
                            0
                        ]
                    },
                    "startTime": "2023-04-28T00:00:00Z",
                    "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Day",
                    "interval": 1,
                    "schedule": {
                        "hours": [
                            "1"
                        ],
                        "minutes": [
                            0
                        ]
                    },
                    "startTime": "2023-04-28T00:00:00Z",
                    "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
   ```

   }

Comment: I already had a Logic App built - I was just missing the App Registration and granting access - thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately,we dont have any default action that can you help you in restarting the app service scaled-out instances one-by-one.

You need to create a custom logic app and by calling the below Azure Management Rest API's using `HTTP` actions.

1. [Web Apps - List Instance Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/list-instance-identifiers) --> To get the list of scale-out instance with their respective name's and ID under a App service.
2. [App Service Plans - Reboot Worker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/app-service-plans/reboot-worker) --> To restart specific worker instances ( for workername property pass the Machine Name pulled from above list operation)

Comment: I was able to create a logic app and iterate thru instance names. But, I think there is some limitation on how often I can reboot workers since I'm getting an error "Cannot modify this web hosting plan because another operation is in progress" when I try to reboot every 3 minutes. Do you have any insights on this?